# Asking coordinates in a form

Tags: forms, geolocation

I have a form with geolocation with google maps. Users can input their location through a map modal with a click or through an autocomplete input.

Problem is google is not omnipresent and some countrys have banned google and google maps api. So the idea of having only texts with info fall and I have to put some inputs with the info (street, postal code,etc.), having latitude and longitude as needed info. The question come now with 3 subsections:

1. Which level of friction I can give to user asking with inputs about that info. It's not something you ask in your common form.
2. If the level of last question is too high. How good or bad is trying to guess it calculating via the info a user enter via normal inputs?
3. And when all the previous questions falls. Even knowing a user could register out of the workplace, how bad is guessing the coordinates looking at the IP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Which level of friction I can give to user asking with inputs about that info. It's not something you ask in your common form.

**A lot**, most users won't know how to do this.

2. If the level of last question is too high. How good or bad is trying to guess it calculating via the info a user enter via normal inputs?

Question 1 answers this.

3. And when all the previous questions falls. Even knowing a user could register out of the workplace, how bad is guessing the coordinates looking at the IP?

I think you can the IP from the users without asking permission, but I would solve this asking the question, and add a caption with "Use my actual location", so the browser can ask permission and use the actual location and print it on the input field.

Another solution, would be the same structure ("Please input your geolocation" + Caption "Don't know how to it? *Learn how*", and use this caption to invoke a modal redirecting a user to a free and safe webpage, opened to all the world, which gets the geolocation of the user.

This one for example: https://gps-coordinates.org/

When you enter the site, it automatically asks your ubication to find it.

Comment: I like the last solution. Having that structure with the modal is way smoother and nearer what I needed. Thanks for your answer, Juan Jesús!